'ERROR:dual_engine_service_win.cc(1346)] Unable to parse SiteList: Data Decoder terminated unexpectedly' cause browser reload page
I'm using Selenium to perform web test by C#. At the begining it works fine. But recently I encountered a problem.
During testing, when Edge web driver returns error 'ERROR:dual_engine_service_win.cc(1346)] Unable to parse SiteList: Data Decoder terminated unexpectedly' the brower will reload the url and cause my test fail.
I found that 'dual_engine_service_win.cc' is related to Edge's dual engine for IE compatibility and this is also related to company group policy.
I tried to find options to disable such dual engine feature but it seems no such options.
Anyone has idea about this issue? Or other work around?

Any chance to provide a minimal code example for us to reproduce this issue? Also, are you running Edge driver or IE driver?
